# Least frequent number in an array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm having problems with this function . I've tested for example this input

> Input : 2 2 3 4 4
>
> Output : 3

It works fine so far. But when I have two or more numbers who are in this particularly situation:

> Input : 1 3 3 4
>
> Output : 4

I keep getting the number with the largest index. What I really wanted was  this Output in that situation ( number with the smallest index ) :

> Output : 1

**This is my code :**

```
int leastFreq (int v[] , int size)
{
  int i ;
  int count = 0;
  int repetitions = 0;
  int lower;

  for ( i = 0 ; i < size ; i ++)
  {
   if (v[i] != v[i+1])
   { 
     count --;
        if ( count < repetitions)
        {
          repetitions = count;
          lower = v[i];
        }
   }
   else 
   { count = 0 ;}  
  }
   return lower;
}
```

**How can I fix this problem ?**
**(This is an sorted array)**

Comment: Is `conta` supposed to be `count`?

Comment: Change `(count < repetitions)` to `(count <= repetitions)` or walk the array in increasing order?

Comment: I think Oehm's comment will fix the problem but you have another error given a FOR statement that counts down to zero, and an IF statement that checks v[i] != v[i-1], then at the end of the loop you will be comparing v[0] != v[-1] which could cause all sorts of wierdness.

Comment: Does the code you show really do what you want? You increase the count (of subsequent equal entries, I guess) when the entries are not equal. You also access `v[i - 1]` when ´i` can be zero.

Comment: I already edited that the array is sorted . It didn't cross my mind that the v[i-1] could be 0 . Thanks for reminding me that . I will try to put the code in the normal order , ( i = 0 ; i < size ; i++).

Comment: Your code now accesses `v[size]`, which is one index beyond the array.

Comment: @JoséCunha you should not edit your code trying to fix it. Now the original question does not seem correct any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code minnum will contain the min fequency number.a[0..size-1]

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{   
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int a[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    int min=65536;
    int minnum=a[0];

    int i,ct=1;
    for(i=1;i<=n-1;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==a[i-1])
        {
            ct++;
        }
        else
        {
            if(ct<min)
            {
                min=ct;
                ct=1;
                minnum=a[i-1];
            }
        }
    }
    if(ct<min)
    {
        min=ct;
        ct=1;
        minnum=a[i-1];
    }
  printf("%d",minnum);
}
```

> The algorithm is
>       First set a variable that implies occurence of a number to maximum possible number.
>
> Then go on checking the equal numbers. When unequality occurs b/w 2 consecutive numbers just check if the number's occurence is less than the prev number's occurence.
>
> Out side the loop it is also checked as it is required when the numbers end in a series of equal number like `1,1,1,2,2`

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work properly. It accesses the array beyond the aray bounds. It favours early subarrays of equal entries regardless of length, because the count isn't really a count. It can go below -1 only when subarrays have the length one.

The problem here is that you must find the length of a subarray befor you do the minimum check. You can do the check when adjacent array entries have different values, but you must be sure to catch the last subarray, too.

The code below uses two nested loops. The outer `while` walks through the subarrays, the inner `while` determines subarrays:

```
int leastFreq(int v[], int size)
{
    int result;
    int min = size + 1;
    int i;

    if (size < 1) return 0;

    i = 0;
    while (i < size) {
        int start = i;
        int val = v[i];
        int count;

        i++;
        while (i < size && v[i] == val) i++;

        count = i - start;
        if (count < min) {
            result = val;
            min = count;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

This will find the first of the shortest subarrays. If you want to find the last, change the condition to `(count <= min)`.